# Executing gradle exe from different location throws "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, gradle

I am new to gradle, I have cloned a project from Github and as mentioned in their QuickGuide I ran `./gradlew build` command to build the Gradle exe.So now I navigate to the folder where the exe is created inside the project and execute it via the command `./exe_name param1 param2`. When I have moved the exe to a different location and try to execute the same command , it throws the error `Error: Could not find or load main class`. How to resolve this issue ? Like in a fat jar we can mention the main class name inside the jar while execution 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure, whether your project uses `application` plugin (or may be `spring-boot` plugin) or not, but if yes, then you have a root project folder with `bin` and `lib` directories within.

`exe` file is located in the `bin` directory and points to the `jar`-libraries within `lib` dir, so if you move it somewhere else, you have to move `lib` directory too, since it contains you project jar and all it's dependencies/

Comment: Thanks a lot , that worked.
BTW the project uses `application` plugin